Compling kernel in CentOS 9
When I was compiling kernel I faced with this error:
** No rule to make target 'certs/rhel.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.

I ran these commands:
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS

scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS

The error above was solved. But I faced with new error:
fatal error: kernel-interfaces/readahead.h: No such file or directory

My linux distribution is CentOS 9 with kernel 5.14.0
What is the problem? Please help. Thanks.

You need the linux-kernel-headers libraries installed since the readahead.h library is part of the. Install the kernel-devel & kernel-headers packages for your centos kernel.
To make sure the correct devel & header versions are installed use the following command:
yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
yum install "kernel-headers-uname-r == $(uname -r)"

Make sure to remove the old ones first and reinstall them again with the above flags.

I used "yum" to install them in terminal, but both of them are already installed. My $(uname -r) is "5.14.0-472.el9.x86_64" but the packages that are already installed are: "kernel-devel-5.14.0-472.el9.x86_64" and "kernel-devel-5.14.0-474.el9.x86_64" for kernel-devel and "kernel-headers-5.14.0-474.el9.x86_64" for kernel-headers. There is a differecne in 472 and 474. Is it important?

I've updated the commands within the answer. You should only have the 5.14.0.-472.xxx devel & headers packages installed, since that's your correct kernel version.

I removed kernel-devel 474 version but kernel-headers version is just 474 (no match argument for kernel-headers-5.14.0-472.xxx). I can install it indepedently or with kernel-devel in its dependencies. May be the problem is related to other packages for compiling like ncurses-devel and ... .

You can provide the name of the kernel-headers you need directly. There is an existing rpm pkg for your particular kernel version found here: link yum install kernel-headers-5.14.0-472.el.x86_64 should work in your case
